# How can I make Fancybox switch to the next or previous gallery upon pressing the 'up' or 'down' arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have a vertical column of thumbnail images, each of which corresponds to its own gallery (of additional images). Presently, when I click a thumbnail image, its Fancybox opens, and then I can press my 'left', 'right', 'up', and 'down' arrow keys to advance to the next or previous images within that respective gallery.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6tmq/

How can I re-map the 'up' and 'down' arrow keys to instead show the first image from the next or previous gallery (rather than the next or previous image within that gallery)?

Effectively, I would like the user to be able to open a Fancybox, and be able to navigate all of the images within all of the galleries (on a given page) without closing the Fancybox.

```
<!-- GALLERY 1 -->
<li>
    <!-- THUMB -->
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
        <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>

    <!-- IN-GALLERY IMAGES -->
    <div class="hidden">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</li>

<!-- GALLERY 2 -->
<li>
    <!-- THUMB -->
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_b.jpg">
        <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_s.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>

    <!-- IN-GALLERY IMAGES -->
    <div class="hidden">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/5_b.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</li>

$(".fancybox")
.fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'over'
        },
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without modifying Fancyboxs source(or writing a plugin(somewhat)), for short it's not possible with their [API](http://fancybox.net/api).

But you could set all the `rel` to `gallery1`, that would allow the user to browse all the images and galleries without closing Fancybox, it would not allow the user to jump between the galleries.

Your `hidden` class could still be used in the same way.

Comment: well, I thinks it's possible (and not need to modify the original source files.) In your custom script, you may need to change the value of the `keys` option (to remove the default settings for `up` and `down` arrows), then use a callback (i.e. `afterShow`) to catch the keystrokes (with the `.keyup()` method) to trigger the next/prev galleries after the `up` and `down` arrows. That's the general idea if someone wants to try (me a bit busy right now.) I just wonder what if there are more than 2 galleries.

Comment: @JFK, yes, there are about 40 galleries on the page. I was reading [the documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) about modifying the key values but don't know enough about javascript to understand if what I want to do is possible.